# How to change custom icon image on hover of the link next to it?

Tags: html, css

How do I get a custom icon image to change on hover of the link next to it? Each image will be different for each link obviously. In my case I have two different coloured images one black and then I need it to change to green when you hover on the link next to it. Can this be done with just CSS or do I need to use JS?

**Edit:**
Explained better. When the user hovers over "Link 1" the `.home-icon` should turn green and when "Link 2" is hovered `.tshirt-icon` should turn green etc

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ifusion/d3ntcxkn/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="home-icon"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="tshirt-icon"></i>Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.home-icon {
    background: url(http://s1.postimg.org/gk5fbl6vv/home_black.png) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;

    &:hover {
        background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/43870q29h/home_green.png) no-repeat;
    }

}

.tshirt-icon {
    background: url(http://s30.postimg.org/61bqc12fh/tshirt_black.png) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;

    &:hover {
        background: url(http://s17.postimg.org/3x9qzn8sb/tshirt_green.png) no-repeat;
    }
}
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ifusion/d3ntcxkn/)

Comment: Let me check if I understand: When user hover on `.home-icon` you went that the `.tshirt-icon` will be green?

Comment: Sorry no let me explain better. When the user hovers over "Link 1" the .home-icon should turn green and when "Link 2" is hovered .tshirt-icon should turn green etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a **direct descendant** selector:

```
a:hover > i {
    background:green;
}
```

Because this gets more specificity than others.

Snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.home-icon {
  background: url("http://s1.postimg.org/gk5fbl6vv/home_black.png") no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a:hover .home-icon {
    background: url("http://s2.postimg.org/43870q29h/home_green.png") no-repeat;
}

.tshirt-icon {
  background: url("http://s30.postimg.org/61bqc12fh/tshirt_black.png") no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a:hover .tshirt-icon {
  background: url("http://s17.postimg.org/3x9qzn8sb/tshirt_green.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="link-1" href="#"><i class="home-icon"></i>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="link-2" href="#"><i class="tshirt-icon"></i>Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can remove the `id` on `<a>` and use directly `a:hover i.tshirt-icon`

Comment: @RohitKumar I have changed. Added it for more specificity

Comment: Thanks guys, this is exactly what I wanted. Even better not having to add an `id` to each link :)

Comment: @ifusion Yea, keeping it cleaner, `id`s are only for JavaScript purposes

Comment: @divy3993 Yup... There can be only a few correct answers and ours are right. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes it is :)

Answer (score 2):

Ya you can try by selecting the immediate sibling of hovered anchor tag using `>`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d3ntcxkn/1/)

**CSS**

```
a:hover >  i
{
    background:green;
}
```

> Note: Add this after all code related to your navigation code

Answer (score 1):

This is a suitable solution.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="link-1" href="#"><i class="home-icon"></i>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="link-2" href="#"><i class="tshirt-icon"></i>Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.home-icon {
  background: url(http://s1.postimg.org/gk5fbl6vv/home_black.png) no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a#link-1:hover .home-icon {
    background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/43870q29h/home_green.png) no-repeat;
}

.tshirt-icon {
  background: url(http://s30.postimg.org/61bqc12fh/tshirt_black.png) no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a#link-2:hover .tshirt-icon {
  background: url(http://s17.postimg.org/3x9qzn8sb/tshirt_green.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for are css selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

> E F   an F element descendant of an E element

css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.icon{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.home-icon {
    background: url(http://s1.postimg.org/gk5fbl6vv/home_black.png) no-repeat;
}
.home-icon-link:hover .home-icon{
    background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/43870q29h/home_green.png) no-repeat;
}

.tshirt-icon {
    background: url(http://s30.postimg.org/61bqc12fh/tshirt_black.png) no-repeat;
}
.tshirt-icon-link:hover .tshirt-icon {
    background:url(http://s17.postimg.org/3x9qzn8sb/tshirt_green.png) no-repeat;
}
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="home-icon-link" href="#"><i class="home-icon icon"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="tshirt-icon-link" href="#"><i class="tshirt-icon icon"></i>Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="home-icon1" href="#"><i class="home-icon"></i>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="tshirt-icon1" href="#"><i class="tshirt-icon"></i>Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.home-icon {
    background: url(http://s1.postimg.org/gk5fbl6vv/home_black.png) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;

    &:hover {
        background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/43870q29h/home_green.png) no-repeat;
    }
}
.tshirt-icon {
    background: url(http://s30.postimg.org/61bqc12fh/tshirt_black.png) no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
        &:hover {
        background: url(http://s17.postimg.org/3x9qzn8sb/tshirt_green.png) no-repeat;
    }
}
.home-icon1{
    &:hover {
        .home-icon {
                      background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/43870q29h/home_green.png) no-repeat;
            width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
            }
        }
    }
}
.tshirt-icon1{
    &:hover {
        .tshirt-icon {
                      background: url(http://s17.postimg.org/3x9qzn8sb/tshirt_green.png) no-repeat;
               width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 20px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will give the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="hoverable" href="#"><i class="home-icon"></i><span class="text">Link 1</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="hoverable" href="#"><i class="tshirt-icon"></i><span class="text">Link 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.home-icon {
  background: url("http://s1.postimg.org/gk5fbl6vv/home_black.png") no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a:hover .home-icon {
    background: url("http://s2.postimg.org/43870q29h/home_green.png") no-repeat;
}

.tshirt-icon {
  background: url("http://s30.postimg.org/61bqc12fh/tshirt_black.png") no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a:hover .tshirt-icon {
  background: url("http://s17.postimg.org/3x9qzn8sb/tshirt_green.png") no-repeat;
}

a#hoverable:hover {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/nv4dw8vr/